# Index out of range fatal error

Tags: arrays, swift

```
func allStrings(inputArray: [String]) -> [String] {
    var a = inputArray
    var b : [String] = []
    var c = a.count


    for i in stride(from: 1, to: c, by: 1) {
        if a[i].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ==      b[0].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            b.append(a[i])
        }
        if a[i].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) > b[0].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            var b = [String]()
            b.append(a[i])
        }

    }

    return b
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong with my code, when I run it, I have this error in the console. Anyone know what's wrong?

> fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Array indices start at **zero** in Swift.

Comment: Also your `b` array is initially **empty** and you must not access `b[0]` – what do you expect that to be?

Comment: Have to tried to *debug* the code? And what are you trying to achieve? In the second if-block, you append to a *local* variable `b`, which is useless.

Answer (score 1):

The error is you're trying to access b which has 0 elements

```
// the array b is empty, so b[0] gives you the error
if a[i].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ==      b[0].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            b.append(a[i])
        }
        if a[i].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) > b[0].lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            var b = [String]()
            b.append(a[i])
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `b` is empty and you are trying to access it's 0th index in your first `if` condition within the loop, which really doesn't exist.